# Open My application with png or jpg file

Tags: ios

I want to show the my app to the user when user use the open in function from the other app.

Here is my code.

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Image File</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.png</string>
            <string>public.jpg</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

What is wrong with that?

ScreeShot

[image]

Comment: That will work in general but keep in mind that the Photos app and the Mail app do not give the option to open image files with 3rd party apps. Is that your issue?

Comment: but for the other application like documents from that is also not showing

Comment: @rmaddy i have also attached the image please see. i think its pproblem in my application

Comment: With the above in your Info.plist, if another 3rd party app uses `UIDocumentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:` for an image file, your app will be listed.